# Adding values of only 4 columns into a MySQL database that has 5 columns

Tags: javascript, mysql

I have a database named 'website' that has a 'users' table, that has 5 columns, respectively they are:

`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `username`, and `password`

I have declared the constructors in a js file called User.js and I have a file UserDB.js that will execute the SQL commands in the registration form in my website to add the details in the database.

As the registration page does not have 'id' (as id is used to add a value increment), I only want to insert the `first_name`, `last_name`, `username`, `password` into the database records that has 5 values but I get the following message with Postman

```
"sqlMessage": "Out of range value for column 'id' at row 1",
```

This is my UserDB.js file, what must I put to not affect the id column?

**UserDB.js**  - Updated

```
    insert(user, callback) {
        var sql = "INSERT INTO website.users VALUES(?,?,?,?)";

        db.query(sql, [user.getFirstName(), user.getLastName(), user.getUsername(), user.getPassword()], callback)
    }
```

Result from Postman:

```
{
    "code": "ER_WRONG_VALUE_COUNT_ON_ROW",
    "errno": 1136,
    "sqlMessage": "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1",
    "sqlState": "21S01",
    "index": 0,
    "sql": "INSERT INTO website.users VALUES('first','last','user','123')"
}
```

**User.js**

```
"use strict";

class User {
    constructor(first_name, last_name, username, password) {
        this.first_name = first_name;
        this.last_name = last_name;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    getFirstName() {
        return this.first_name;
    }

    getLastName() {
        return this.last_name;
    }

    getUsername() {
        return this.username;
    }

    getPassword() {
        return this.Password;
    }    
}

module.exports = User;
```

Comment: Just specify column names like that `insert into users (first_name, last_name, username, password) values ('John', 'Doe', 'johney', '*****');`

Comment: I want to do it the way as above because I am retrieving each variable by using 'get' , like `getFirstName()`, because I'm making a registration form

Answer (score 0):

try this 
DB.js :

```
insert(user, callback) {
    var sql = "INSERT INTO website.users (`first_name`,`last_name`,`username`,`password`) VALUES(?,?,?,?)";

    db.query(sql, [user.getFirstName(), user.getLastName(), user.getUsername(), user.getPassword()], callback)
}
```

i have removed the id column from insert query and assuming that the column `id is auto-increment`

Updated the below part ,please have a look :

```
    getPassword() {
           return this.Password;
       }
```

replace this with ..

```
      getPassword() {
             return this.password;
         }
```

there is a difference of variable name .

Comment: I have already tried this and gotten `Column count doesn't match value count at row 1",`

Comment: is that column ```id``` is autoincrement

Comment: This is what i have used 
  [`id` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`]

Comment: try the above update (this.password)  i guess that would be the mistake.

Comment: try removing ```use strict```

Answer (score 0):

Just specify the fields you want to insert explicitly:

```
INSERT INTO website.users (first_name,last_name,username,password) VALUES(?,?,?,?);
```

Also remove the first value in php code:

```
db.query(sql, [user.getFirstName(), user.getLastName(), user.getUsername(), user.getPassword()], callback);
```

Fields not specified will be filled with a value automatically if there is no problem with your DDL.

---

The code here is OK now, but your data have been contaminated. So what you should do now is:

1. Remove all invalid rows in your table.
2. Alter your DDL with: `ALTER TABLE users AUTO_INCREMENT = 6; --replace it with the right value`

And then everything will be fine.

Comment: I have already tried this and gotten `Column count doesn't match value count at row 1",`

Comment: Did you forget to reduce a `?`

Comment: Nope.  I only have 4 `?`

Comment: Have you removed the first element `''` for array in the subsequent statement?

Comment: Yes I have. I have updated the codes in my questions so you may take a look.

Comment: well..try again with the SQL statement I provided you, please.

Comment: I got it.Look at your DDL: `AUTO_INCREMENT = 2147483648`, `id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT`. the `id` field is out of range obviously. It means your code is OK, but the table can't hold more records! That's the problem.

Comment: In other words, you should modify your DDL, and the code should not  be  to blame

Comment: Hmm, but I only have five records at the moment

Comment: You have probably inserted a bad value for `id`, and that contaminate the data, that's why `AUTO_INCREMENT = 2147483648`.

Comment: I have changed the structure and still getting the same thing. Do you mind continuing this in chat?

Comment: OK, chat with me

Comment: I do not have enough rep to start the chat, could you invite me?

Comment: search and join `walter's room`